# Give <Select> options a border

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to give the container of the `<Select>` options a border? The `<Select>` tag implements a `<Popover>` with a `<Menu>` component on which the `<MenuItem>`s options are rendered, but the documentation does not detail how this container can be styled.

There is an option to apply props to the menu via `MenuProps`, but it is not clear in the examples/documentation how a border could be applied to it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-2cdqs?fontsize=14

```
import ...;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    containerWithBorder: {
      paper: {
        border: "1px solid red"
      }
    }
  })
);

function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          MenuProps={{ // Can this be used to give the options a border? 
            classes: classes.containerWithBorder
          }}
          value={values.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          inputProps={{
            name: "age",
            id: "age-simple"
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SimpleSelect;
```

Comment: Have you tried giving it a className and editing its style in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you would do is write your style in the in the override useStyles section

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    select: {
      border: "1px solid black",
    },
  }),
);
```

like this and then you would pass it to the Select component:

```
<Select className={classes.select} />
```

like this

Comment: if this solves your problem please mark as the answer so i get credit

Comment: This puts a border around the select input, not the select options wrapper. https://puu.sh/DBRTi/0ac3c10d5b.png

Comment: okay so write classes.select in the <MenuItem className={classes.select}/> component